# NightmareJS persist session between tests

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, nightmare

I am using NightmareJS with Mocha. Everything seems to work fine, but I have problem separating tests as my session does not persist through different test cases.

First test is passing fine, but then the second test `Should be able to edit` fails, as I end up on the same login page even though I am using the partition option. How can I overcome this?

```
require('mocha-generators').install();
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var expect = require('chai').expect;

describe('Nightmare JS tests', function() {
  this.timeout(30000);

  var url = 'http://localhost/app/';

  describe('base functionality', function() {

    it('Should be able to login', function*() {
        var nightmare = Nightmare({
            show: true,
            'webPreferences': {
                partition: 'persist:somesession'
            }
        });
        var result = yield nightmare
                .goto(url)
                .wait('.login')
                .click('.login')
                .wait('h4.heading')
                .wait(1000)
                .evaluate(function () {
                    return document.querySelector('h4.heading').innerHTML;

                })
                .end();

        expect(result).to.equal("This is heading");

    });

    it('Should be able to edit', function*() {
        var nightmare = Nightmare({
            show: true,
            'webPreferences': {
                partition: 'persist:somesession'
            }
        })
        var result = yield nightmare
                .goto('http://localhost/app/company')
                .wait("button.edit")
                .click("button.edit")
                .wait("input[type='text']")
                .insert("input[type='text']", false)
                .insert("input[type='text']", "This is some address")

                .click("button[type='submit']")
                .wait("div.success")
                .evaluate(function () {
                    return document.querySelector("div.success").innerText;

                })
                .end()

        expect(result).to.contain("Updated!");

    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There has been some discussion around this topic on the Nightmare Github project (see [#430](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/issues/430) and [#398](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare/issues/398) for more information) in regards to sharing sessions.  The TL;DR version is you can reset the session, but using the same session across instances is not well tested.  (Judging from your example, it looks like you may have seen these already.)

At any rate, I think I can help address your immediate problem.  Two suggestions:

1. **Use the same instance.**  You could move the creation of the Nightmare instance to a `before()` block and use the same instance for your tests.  This introduces test dependency, though, and is generally considered undesirable.
2. **Move the entire login process to a `beforeEach()` block.** Move the entirety of the login unit test to a `beforeEach()` block so you get a fresh login for every test.  You also will want to add a `afterEach()` block to clean up the nightmare instance.  This will make your tests independently runnable, but also introduces substantial time overhead for running an entire unit test battery.

An (untested) example of #2 based on your sample may be helpful:

```
require('mocha-generators').install();
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var expect = require('chai').expect;

describe('Nightmare JS tests', function() {
  this.timeout(30000);

  var url = 'http://localhost/app/';

  describe('base functionality', function() {
    var nightmare;
    beforeEach(function*() {
      nightmare = Nightmare({
        show: true,
      });
      yield nightmare
        .goto(url)
        .wait('.login')
        .click('.login')
        .wait('h4.heading')
        .wait(1000)
    });

    afterEach(function*() {
      yield nightmare.end();
    });

    it('Should be able to edit', function*() {
      var result =
        yield nightmare
        .goto('http://localhost/app/company')
        .wait("button.edit")
        .click("button.edit")
        .wait("input[type='text']")
        .insert("input[type='text']", false)
        .insert("input[type='text']", "This is some address")

      .click("button[type='submit']")
        .wait("div.success")
        .evaluate(function() {
          return document.querySelector("div.success").innerText;

        });
      expect(result).to.contain("Updated!");

    });
  });
```

Comment: Thanks Ross for pointing out the Github issues and suggesting alternative ways. Excellent answer :)

Comment: Great answer. Worked as needed the first time I used it.